# Generating a random graph with equal node degree?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, networkx

I am trying to generate a simple undirected random graph with N number of nodes that has all the degrees of nodes equal. for example, let's say all the node has degree equal to k.
I just started using the networkx package and discovered that it offers a variety of random graph generation. Can someone tell me if it is possible to generate a graph where each of the nodes has an equal degree?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use the [random_regular_graph()](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.generators.random_graphs.random_regular_graph.html#networkx.generators.random_graphs.random_regular_graph) function to generate a graph uniformly at random from all graphs with `n` nodes and degree `k`:

```py
import networkx as nx

k = 5
num_nodes = 10
random_graph = nx.random_regular_graph(d=k, n=num_nodes)
```

Comment: thank you so much; it is helpful.